# Name mangling of C/C++ on x64

Tags: c++, c, curl, static-libraries, calling-convention

Now I am building a C library, libcurl for Win64 application. The building looks successful, and a libcurl.lib has been generated. However during linking libcurl to the application, there are errors like:

`20>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: calloc already defined in MabMem.lib(malloc.obj)
20>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: free already defined in MabMem.lib(malloc.obj)
20>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: malloc already defined in MabMem.lib(malloc.obj)
20>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: realloc already defined in MabMem.lib(malloc.obj)`

I think the reason is that libcurl is calling these functions from stdlib, however the existing project have defined its own methods, which causes conflicts. On Win32 it looks like this kind of problem could be resolved by setting the compiling options to /Gv, which could add a "_" at the beginning of the function name to make "malloc" "_malloc" to avoid this conflict. But MSDN states that on x64, __cdecl is typically ignored. Actually I have tried every calling convention options to build libcurl, but every time when using objdump to observe libcurl.lib, there is no _malloc but only malloc, means no convention has been made.

So how to enable this kind of calling convention on x64 building? Or maybe there are other solutions? I don't want to modify the MabMem library, and of course I cannot modify stdlib.h....

Edit1: To make it a bit more accurate. Because I know not much about MSVC, maybe this will help. My target is building libcurl for win64, and I found an existing built library for win32, but I don't have the vcproj file and don't know its configuration. The existing win32 library file, when using objdump to observe it, I can find malloc has been imported as _malloc, which can avoid collision with other libraries. However, the win64 project, which setup by me, just generate lib files with malloc imported as malloc. I am actually trying to find out how to build a library, on WIN64, which imports malloc as _malloc.

Comment: So, your project on Win32 is meant to build only with a specific compiler behaviour together with a specific calling convention, because you want to have multiple functions with same names, and the problem is that Win64 is different? You should change your project. Use namespaces or rename your own functions.

Comment: "C/C++" is *not* a thing. You need decide which you're using and say so, because it matters.